# how to delete a json element in mogodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

Following is the content in `mongodb` like this:

```
{
"_id": 74924,
"bangs": {
    "436": {
        "join_time": 1345624851,
        "status": 1,
        "scores": 0
    },
    "446": {
        "join_time": 1355727257,
        "status": 1,
        "scores": 0
    }
},
"_id": 74926,
"bangs": {
    "436": {
        "join_time": 1345624851,
        "status": 1,
        "scores": 0
    },
    "446": {
        "join_time": 1355727257,
        "status": 1,
        "scores": 0
    }
 }
}
```

I want to delete :

```
"436": {
        "join_time": 1345624851,
        "status": 1,
        "scores": 0
    },
 where _id=74924
```

The result will be:

```
{
"_id": 74924,
"bangs": {
    "446": {
        "join_time": 1355727257,
        "status": 1,
        "scores": 0
    }
},
"_id": 74926,
"bangs": {
    "436": {
        "join_time": 1345624851,
        "status": 1,
        "scores": 0
    },
    "446": {
        "join_time": 1355727257,
        "status": 1,
        "scores": 0
    }
 }
}
```

I wrote the code like this:

```
$mongo->users->users->update(array('_id'=>74924), array('$pull'=>array('bangs'=>436)));
```

But the record didn't remove

How can i write the code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it with this:

```
db.test.update( { _id:74924 }, { $unset: {"bangs.436":1} } )

// I think this can be written in php like this:
$mongo->users->users->update(array('_id'=>74924), array('$unset'=>array('bangs.436'=>1)));
```